# Problem Installation of Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot

I recently tried to install Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio laptop (Windows 7, 64 bits). I downloaded the .iso file from Ubuntu website and burned it on a DVD.

But when I booted the laptop with the DVD, I got first the keypad icon, then chose the language and the choice whether to Install or Try Ubuntu. Whatever choice I made, it seems that it stops working, I got a black screen, I could not hear the DVD turning, etc...

I also tried to boot with a USB, same story. And I also tried to boot another computer from the DVD and this time I worked. So I don't think the CD wasn't burned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problems you experienced I have had many time over. What I have done for to keep from having that same issue, I download the .iso files via a torrent. Once downloaded I make bootable flash drives and go from there.

I am not saying this is full-proof but it works for me about 98% of the time!

Comment: Well that won't fix my problem because i downloaded the iso file from the torrent link the Ubuntu website give us.... But thanks anyway!